# @openzeppelin/contracts import failed

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, import

[image: The Errors that i am getting when i am trying to compile the contract]

The issue I am having is when I am trying to compile my contract, I am getting multiple errors for ERC721. As imported ERC721 is importing more contracts, as seen from the errors, the issue is that it is not found. I have installed openzeppelin globally and internally through npm, but the issue remains... I ran out of ideas to solve this issue and test my contract...
I am adding the picture to have a broad idea of what I am dealing with.
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your imports to:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

Comment: Just tried it, still same issue all same errors come up when trying to compile... i also double checked what version of Openzeppelin contracts i have installed with npm and it shows the latest, v4.8.0